# How can i pass 1 or more items in an other activity

Tags: android

i need a hand with my code... i got a listview multi columns full of items,and  i want to pass 3 items in an other activity and save it  when i clicked in any row... then go back to list in selected other row ... again , again and again    like a shopping cart
This my code `

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    GetContacts get = new GetContacts();
    String datas=get.doInBackground().toString();
    Log.d("RESULT",datas);
        int id = info.position;
    View view=info.targetView;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case  R.id.iva:
            TextView textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);
            TextView textView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescrip);
            TextView textView5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);

            String text3 = textView3.getText().toString();
            String text4 = textView4.getText().toString();
            String text5 = textView5.getText().toString();
            Intent intent3= new Intent(busqueda.this,Carrito.class);

            intent3.putExtra("CODE",text3);
            intent3.putExtra("PRODUC",text4);
            intent3.putExtra("PRECIO",text5);


            startActivity(intent3);
    }
```

return true;

And the other Activity only receive 1 row ....

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito);
    texto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    txtcod=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    txtpre=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    if (extra != null) {
        String dato = extra.getString("CODE");
        String Tok = extra.getString("PRODUC");
        String Token2 = extra.getString("PRECIO");

        texto.setText(dato);
        txtcod.setText(Tok);
        txtpre.setText(Token2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `intent3.putStringArrayListExtra("name", arrayList);`

This way you can put whole columns of strings in at once instead of one at a time.

Comment: should i have an other listview in the second activity too?

Comment: You should have another _ArrayList_ in the second activity